# stylesheets-remove in .info.yml file doesn't work

Tags: 8, theming

I'm following [Drupal 8 Theming Fundamentals, Part 1](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1) to create a Drupal 8 theme. They say that default CSS styles are added by modules in the core as shown in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

Those CSS files can be removed from the .info.yml theme file using code similar to the following one.

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - core/assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css
  - core/modules/system/css/system.module.css
  - core/modules/system/css/system.theme.css
  - core/modules/views/css/views.module.css
```

I've done that, but nothing happens (it's says the same). Plus, when I watch to the source of the page, I see the following.

> [image: screenshot]

The CSS styles are aggregrated. What is happening here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you rebuild the cache?

Comment: @Clive, yes I've rebuild the cache ..

Comment: Here is ofic doc https://www.drupal.org/node/2349827 and it looks like you are doing it right. Try debugging \Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeInitialization::prepareStylesheetsRemove maybe you will find something.

Comment: Before you start debugging, switch off "Aggregate CSS files" in /admin/config/development/performance

Answer (score 7):

I was also having trouble with this and I found a [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2473869) which states:

> "In cases where a Drupal core asset is being removed (for example, a
>   CSS file in jQuery UI) the full file path is needed. In cases where
>   the file is part of a library that belongs to a module or theme, a
>   token can be used. Note that when using the token it needs to be
>   quoted because @ is a reserved indicator in YAML."

In my case I was trying to remove the eu_cookie_compliance.css file from the eu_cookie_compliance module. To do this I used the following in mytheme.info.yml:

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - '@eu_cookie_compliance/css/eu_cookie_compliance.css'
```

To remove module (even core ones) provided css you could try something like:

```
'@system/css/system.module.css'
```

To answer your second question about the aggregation of css files, you can switch off aggregation by visiting `/admin/config/development/performance` and unchecking "Aggregate and compress CSS files"

Comment: This answer explains why the *stylesheets-remove* directive in the .info.yml file doesn't work. It would be a nice add if the answer would explain why the CSS files are suddenly aggregrated.